# A more elegant way to add a list of tags to resid_compare graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

My journal requires combined graphs to be labeled by panels. Doing the following gives me the "A" tag only.

```
library(ggResidpanel); library(patchwork)


penguin_model <- lme4::lmer(heartrate ~ depth + duration + (1|bird), data = penguins)
penguin_model_log2 <- lme4::lmer(log(heartrate) ~ depth + duration + I(duration^2) +
(1|bird), data = penguins)

resid_compare(list(penguin_model, penguin_model_log2)) + labs(tag = list("A" , "B" ))
```

switching to `labs(tag = c("A" , "B" ))` doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Plotting each of the diagnosis graphs and combine them returns what I need. I'm OK doing the `patchwork` for 2 diagnosis panels but it would be nice to be able to use a one-line command in the `resid_compare` if I have 6 panels to display.

```
A <- resid_panel(penguin_model, nrow = 4) + labs(tag = "A")
 
B <- resid_panel(penguin_model_log2, nrow = 4) + labs(tag = "B")

A | B
```

[image]

Note: The images look muddled here but they look OK in knitted pdf.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a one-liner but one option would be to put your models in a list, use `lapply` to make the plots for each model, use `patchwork::wrap_plots` to glue them together and use `patchwork::plot_annotation` to add the tags:

```r
library(ggResidpanel)
library(patchwork)
library(magrittr)

penguin_model <- lme4::lmer(heartrate ~ depth + duration + (1|bird), data = penguins)
penguin_model_log2 <- lme4::lmer(log(heartrate) ~ depth + duration + I(duration^2) +
                                   (1|bird), data = penguins)

list(penguin_model, penguin_model_log2) %>% 
  lapply(resid_panel, nrow = 4) %>% 
  wrap_plots() +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

[image]